# Quando usare: mercatino, mercato, supermercato, ipermercato

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Se entro in un supermercato di piccole dimensioni, perché non lo chiamo semplicemente "mercato"? Non è contro senso chiamarlo "piccolo supermercato"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Se entro in un supermercato di **piccole dimensioni**, perché non lo chiamo semplicemente "mercato"? Non è contro senso chiamarlo "piccolo
>   supermercato"?*

Il prefisso 'super' non si riferisce alla grandezza. Fino agli anni settanta le licenze comunali per le 'botteghe' o 'negozi' erano rigidamente regolate: la 'latteria' poteva vendere solo latte, fino agli anni '50 (nel '53 Roma ebbe una delle prime 'centrale del latte'), il vinaio o 'cantina' vendeva vino e olio, la 'drogheria' (fino agli anni '50) e poi 'salumeria' poteva vendere salumi etc., il 'fruttivendolo' ancora oggi può vendere solo frutta, ortaggi edi recente succhi di frutta etc.

Negli anni sessanta si cominciò a concedere deroghe limitate, aggiungendo qualche articolo industriale collegato al settore merceologico. Se si eccedeva si veniva multati dai 'vigili urbani' che pattugliavano le strade e controllavano che venisse rispettato rigorosamente l'orario di chiusura (alle 8:30 d'estate) e alle 8:40 già fioccavano le multe.

Negli anni settanta e ottanta si adeguò la normativa allo stile europeo ed americano, permettendo ai negozianti al dettaglio di vendere ogni genere di merci (con il self-service) ma mancava un termine adeguato, quelli con una licenza più ampia provarono a metter l'insegna 'alimenti', 'alimentari', ma non potevono vendere, ad esempio i detersivi, chi poteva farlo usavano un vecchio termine 'emporio'. Dall'altro canto c'erano i 'grandi magazzini' ( da prima della guerra), tra cui la mitica STANDA (che fu la prima, solo a Milano, però, nel'60 a sperimentare il self-service) che vendevano di tutto tranne gli alimentari. Solo in seguito, come certo sapete, hanno avuto il permesso di vendere ortofrutta. Dapprima si diffusero le insegne straniere 'self-service', 'supermarket' (che erano anche piccolissimi), poi hanno recuperato le forme italiane:

- *supermercato* vende di tutto (dall'inglese)
- *superette* (dal francese) è un supermercato che ha anche un angolo con un 'salumaio' che affetta mortadella, provolone, etc su richiesta del cliente. Praticamente una salumeria allargata, un mini-market
- *ipermercato*, questo sì è un **grande** supermercato
- *mercato* (comunale) è tutta un'altra cosa: uno spazio (chiuso o all'aperto) che viene concesso ai venditori ambulanti tutti i giorni
- *mercatino* può essere o un mercato *rionale* aperto una volta alla settimana, o uno privato

Comment: Interessante. Comunque superette non l'avevo mai sentito. I supermercati col salumaio li ho sempre chiamati supermercati e basta... Cercando su google e specificando la lingua italiana, con supermercato vengono fuori 11 milioni di pagine, con superette 50000.

Comment: Dove si usa *superette*? Non l'ho mai sentito.

Comment: Ottima risposta! Apparentemente le superette sono diffuse in [piccoli paesi o quartieri cittadini](http://argomenti.ilsole24ore.com/parolechiave/superette.html), «_dove il servizio ha un peso maggiore e si crea un rapporto di familiarità con la clientela_».

Comment: bobie, ottima risposta, bravo. Comunque ho cancellato i commenti off-topic sotto. bobie, @randomatlabuser, DaG, se davvero volete continuare questa discussione, potete farlo in chat, ma per favore, state cortesi e gentili.

Answer (score 3):

Perché si tratta di esposizioni e vendite di merci organizzate in maniera significativamente diversa:

[Mercato](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/mercato.shtml):

> - Riunione di venditori e compratori in luoghi e tempi fissi: il m. settimanale; il luogo generalmente all'aperto deputato a tali scambi commerciali; fiera: m. del bestiame; andare al m. || m. all'ingrosso, quello in cui si vendono esclusivamente in grandi quantità merci per il commercio al dettaglio | m. generali, nelle grandi città, quelli in cui si raccolgono beni di consumo provenienti dalla produzione, da smistare ai m. al minuto | m. delle pulci, quello in cui si vendono oggetti vecchi o usati.

[Supermercato](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/supermercato.shtml):

> - Vasta struttura organizzata per la vendita di prodotti, soprattutto alimentari e domestici, in cui il cliente si serve da solo pagando l'importo totale alle casse poste all'uscita.

Answer (score 1):

perché in "supermercato" il senso originale della parola "super" si è perso (ma anche quello di "mercato", in un certo senso). Per indicare un "piccolo supermercato" si usano così prestiti da altre lingue, come "minimarket" e "superette".